# Assign two values to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Using below script I successfully use to check `.zip file` created for each Application on a specific date and at a specific Destination to get confirmed whether my Backup is successful or not.

Till now I use to check Backup Time only for `_2230` but now I also want to include `_2250` in this check.

So what I did is just changed: `BACKUPTIME="_2230 _2250"`, but It doesn't seem to be working as I'm neither getting `SUCCESSFUL` nor `FAILED` status in Log.

1. Can you please direct me where is the problem in my script ?
2. Could it have any impact on the speed of script I mean adding more
   TIME (_2230 and now _2250) to test for Backup ?

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   DATE=`date +%Y%m%d -d "1 days ago"`
   DESTINATION="/Network/Storage/Backup"
   LOG="/Network/Storage/Backup"
   BACKUPTIME="_2230"

   APPLICATION="DATADEV TESTREV PRETEST"

   for C in $APPLICATION
   do

   cd $DESTINATION/$C/

   test -f $C$DATE$BACKUPTIME.zip

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
   echo "Backup SUCCESSFUL" >>$LOG/output.txt

   else
   echo "Backup FAILED" >>$LOG/output.txt

   fi

   done
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using array:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    DATE=`date +%Y%m%d -d "1 days ago"`
    DESTINATION="/Network/Storage/Backup"
    LOG="/Network/Storage/Backup"
    BACKUPTIMES=(_2230 _2250)                   #Declare an array

    APPLICATION="DATADEV TESTREV PRETEST"

    for C in $APPLICATION
    do
        cd $DESTINATION/$C/
        success=false
        for BACKUPTIME in ${BACKUPTIMES[@]}; do #Iterate over the array
            test -f $C$DATE$BACKUPTIME.zip && success=true
        done
        if $success
        then
            echo "Backup SUCCESSFUL" >>$LOG/output.txt
        else
            echo "Backup FAILED" >>$LOG/output.txt
        fi
    done
```

Note: I have done minimal modification to your code, for easier understanding. There is still scope for optimization.

Comment: Its giving 6 messages in Log while I have only 3 Applications to check. It seems like its checking each application against both times (_2230 _2250) but despite of printing a single SUCCESS/FAILURE its printing 2 results per application for two times. But unfortunately that can't be the case as the backup of a single application is taken either on 2230 OR 2250 NOT at both times so only one message per application is expected.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it

```sh
dya=$(date +%y%m%d -d '1 days ago')
for fdr in datadev testrev pretest
do
  cd /network/storage/backup/$fdr
  pas=1
  for chk in ${fdr}${dya}_{2230,2250}
  do
    [ -f "$chk" ] || pas=0
  done
  (
    printf 'backup '
    (( pas )) && echo successful || echo failed
  ) >> /network/storage/backup/output.txt
done
```

Comment: Its giving 6 messages in Log while I have only 3 Applications to check. It seems like its checking each application against both times (_2230 _2250) but despite of printing a single SUCCESS/FAILURE its printing 2 results per application for two times. But unfortunately that can't be the case as the backup of a single application is taken either on 2230 OR 2250 NOT at both times so only one message per application is expected.